# How to write the list in OCaml?

Tags: list, ocaml

If I want to write `list.ml` in OCaml,

---

**Q1**

which way is correct?

```
type 'a list = 
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * ('a list)
```

or

```
type 'a list = 
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * 'a list
```

Any differences?

---

**Q2**

Also, how do I define the `Cons` inside the type definition as `::`?

---

**Q3**

How do I define `Nil` inside the type definition as `[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q1** - 
There is no difference; each has two parameters associated to `Cons`. Although, `Cons of ('a * 'a list)` is different since it has one parameter, a tuple. You will come across that as an important distinction if you construct a tuple and try to wrap it in `Cons` as in, `let x = a,Nil in Cons x`. The choice depends on how you plan on constructing elements or some semantics of the data. In this particular case, no parenthesis should be used.

**Q2** -
You cannot use `:` as the first character of infix function names as it is a keyword in the language -- `::` is also a keyword regardless. In general infix operators can be defined with parenthesis around the function name and there is a [special set of symbols](http://askra.de/software/ocaml-doc/4.00/lex.html#xhtoc10) allowed,

```
let (!!) a b = Cons( a,b )
```

**Q3** - 
This would require naming an identifier `[]`, as in `let [] = Nil`. Those characters are not allowed in the naming conventions (see same link as above) as they are also individually keywords.